# Pyspark not logging to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, user-defined-functions, tee

I am launching a pyspark script with the command `spark-submit` redirecting the standard output to file too with `tee` to have a log.

The command is the following:

```
spark-submit test.py  | tee test.xxx
```

The problem is that **only** the `print` inside user defined function `UDF` got printed only on the Terminal but not to the file `tee test.xxx` while all the the other prints will both write to terminal and file.

To simulate this behaviour I created this minimal complete working example:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
import pyspark.sql.functions as F #udf, col, count, sum, when, avg, mean, min
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *
def cutURL(input):
    cutURL.lineNumber += 1
    if input==None or input=="" or not(isinstance(input, str)):
        print("WARNING: not proper string URL: empty or null. Possible line: " + str(cutURL.lineNumber))
        res = "Unknown"
        if input==None: print("string is none")
        elif not(isinstance(input, str)): print("input not a string")
        elif input=="": print("empty string")
        return res
    res = input
    try:
        if (bool(re.search("/devices(.+?)&maxdist=[0-9]+", input))):
            res = re.search("/devices(.+?)&maxdist=[0-9]+", input).group()
        else:
            res = re.sub(r'.*?(/devices/[^/]*_)[^/_]*(/read)', r'\1\2', input)
    except:
        print("WARning in cutURL:")
        print(" not matching regular expression: is the string")
    return res


sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sc.setLogLevel("WARN")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
cutURL.lineNumber = 0
print("This will be printed to both file and terminal")
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([None, "example",  "others"], "string").toDF("url")
cut_URL_udf =  F.udf(cutURL, StringType())
df2 = df.select(cut_URL_udf("url").alias("cut_URL"))
df2.show()
```

In this case the string `WARNING: not proper string URL: empty or null. Possible line:` got printed only on terminal but not to file.

How can make output generated inside a pyspark UDF redirected to file too?

**EDIT**
To explain better my problem I add the line `print("This will be printed to both file and terminal")`. This one will be printed to terminal and logged to file while the `print` inside udf only to terminal.

Comment: i think the problem is that pyspark is *probably* changing your stdout, so when you "print" it doesnt go to the stdout directly and thus bypassing tee. you will probably need to control your output handle manually or use the logging module to not reinvent the wheel

Comment: But why is it changing only for the print inside the udf?

Comment: unfortunately i am unfamiliar with pyspark so i cannot answer that with any certainty, but its possible that it opens its own process and handles outputs according to its own internal logic, that is a fairly common behavior

Answer (score 0):

Edit: sorry misread the already redirecting

A solution is to use proper logging instead of printing:

lookup python logging:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html
- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html

Example to log to console and file:

```
import logging

# set up logging to file - see previous section for more details
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='/temp/myapp.log',
                    filemode='w')
# define a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
# set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
# tell the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
# add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

# Now, we can log to the root logger, or any other logger. First the root...
logging.info('Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz.')
```

Comment: Am I not redirecting to file with tee? In my original program everything is being printed both to file and terminal except this part inside the udf